# Why are products in the category with Mage::app('default') but not with Mage::app('admin')?

Tags: magento, collections, count, categories, product

I wrote an extension and in this extension I need the count of active products of a category.

I used this snipped to determine active products by category:

```
 $return = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->load($category->getId())
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
        ->count();
```

If I call the function to get the count of active products in my test.php

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once "app/Mage.php";
Mage::reset();
Mage::app('default');

var_dump(myDummyFunction($categoryObject));
```

I get 3 as the result. If I use the same function within the same magento in the extension (which is used in the admin area) the result is 0.

Has somebody an idea why this happens and how to fix this?

Btw: If I change the Mage::app('default'); in the test.php to Mage::app('admin'); it also displays 0...

Comment: use this Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);  just before the Mage::app('default');

Comment: works like charm ... thank you very much ! 
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(MY_STORE_ID_WHERE_IT_WORKS);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Just Before this

```
Mage::app('default');
```